# ExtJS: Catching events from views in controller ? A leaner approach?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have been using the "control" of a controller to listen to events from my view. I tried to combine 2 buttons under a gridpanel but  the events don't arrive. Am i doing something wrong ? Is there a better way?

Below I am using 1 grid panel and then 2 buttons (item id's).

```
    this.control(
        {
          'my-grid-panel' : {
                '#completeTextfield': {
                    change: {
                        fn: me.doSearch,
                        buffer: 1000
                    }
                },
                '#searchGloballyCheckbox': {
                    change: me.onSearchGlobally
                }
            }
           ......
```

The only way I got it to work was to expand remove the itemIds from being a child of my-grid-panel and placing 2 separate items under this.control. Takes up more room. Any alternatives?

```
    'my-grid-panel #completeTextfield' : {
                    change: {
                        fn: me.doSearch,
                        buffer: 1000
                    },
    'my-grid-panel #searchGloballyCheckbox': {
                    change: me.onSearchGlobally
                }
            }
```

Comment: No, it doesn't support nesting selector likes that. #2 is the approach you need to use.

Comment: Similar thing has been solved in ExtJS5 in a different way(http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.app.ViewController).